# SPARQLWrapper HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, sparql, http-status-code-401, virtuoso, sparqlwrapper

I secured my SPARQL endpoint via SQL Accounts according to [VirtSPARQLProtectSQLDigestAuthentication](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSPARQLProtectSQLDigestAuthentication).

Before this operation, I can get the data through the code:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, DIGEST   

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://example.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("...") 
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

And after that, I use the DIGEST way to get the data,

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, DIGEST

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://example.org/sparql")

sparql.setHTTPAuth(DIGEST)
sparql.setCredentials('login', 'password')

sparql.setQuery("...")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

results = sparql.query().convert()
```

, Error 401 occured:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "1.py", line 21, in 
>       results = sparql.query().convert()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py",
>   line 601, in query
>       return QueryResult(self._query())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py",
>   line 581, in _query
>       raise e urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Anything wrong with my operations? The username and password are both correct.

Appreciate that if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found the answer just several minutes after I wrote the problem, which reminds me of RTFSC again.

line 574~581 in Wrapper.py :

```
elif self.http_auth == DIGEST:
    realm = "SPARQL"
    pwd_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgr()
    pwd_mgr.add_password(realm, uri, self.user, self.passwd)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(pwd_mgr))
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Besides `user` and `password`, there is another varible,`realm`.(default value is `"SPARQL"`), but [VirtSPARQLProtectSQLDigestAuthentication](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSPARQLProtectSQLDigestAuthentication) set the realm as `"SPARQL Endpoint"`.

So the solution is just changing your virtuoso's realm to `"SPARQL"`.