# client to perform authorized access to protected sparql endpoint

Tags: authentication, sparql, virtuoso

I wonder if there are libraries (preferably NodeJS based, like [this client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtuoso-sparql-client)), to gain access to a protected endpoint, hosted by an https server.

Of course, I have access rights, so when I access the endpoint (I enter the url in browser' address bar), I'm requested to enter my authentication tokens, and so get access to the virtuoso sparql query interface.

If I open another browser on the same endpoint, it doesn't ask again my identity - so - the interface it's cookie based. But I haven't found so far a way to give the interface the required tokens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read [these](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideSPARQLEndpoints) pages? Perhaps they are helpful in somewhat way. BTW, your question should be flagged.

Comment: @StanislavKralin: the [most interesting thing](http://ods.openlinksw.com/wiki/ODS/VirtPubSubHub) I found there... There is almost nothing for the client side...

Comment: Perhaps @TallTed will help you or will suggest to ask your question on the [Virtuoso users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users)...

Comment: @StanislavKralin: thanks. By now, I subscribed to the mailing list. ASAP I'll ask there for some help...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254935/sparqlwrapper-http-error-401-unauthorized — In Python using SPARQLWrapper, for Digest Authentication.

Comment: @StanislavKralin: thanks again. I'm currently exploring the CORS path, since the 'DB' administrator enabled it after I got the hint on the mailing list. WRT the question/answer you linked, I've tried (using SWI-Prolog SPARQL client) to access with basic or digest authentication... no luck so far...